# How to document exceptions?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, documentation, comments

Often methods in VB.Net `throw` exceptions. How can I write the code or documentary comments to allow possible exception `throw`s to pop-up when the method is used in code? (Like the way a method's summary pops up.)

The point is to show the testers or other users of the method what exception(s) to expect.

Comment: What do you mean? Yes, you can throw exceptions using the command Throw New Exception(Message).

Comment: As I read in C# there is a way to document an exception that custom method throws
    /// <summary>the method's summary</summary>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">some     comment</exception>
But I am afraid that does not work in vb.

Comment: Can you post the C# code? have you tried the C# to VB converters that are online? e.g. http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Thanks, Mych. I tried [link](C# XML documentation) As I mentioned it is weird but it seems exception tags doesn't work for VB.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`<exception>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w1htk11d.aspx) tag in the XML documentation of a method.

Comment: Thanks, @Dominic Kexel, but I am afraid I tried the XML documentation and the exception doesn't pop-up. Trying the same in C# results in showing the exception below the summary in a pop-up when method is used in code. But in VB only summary is showed but not and the exceptions thrown.

Comment: Sorry, but Intellisence in VB.Net won't show you the exceptions like it does in C#. But you should still use the `<exception>` tag since the Object Browser does read this tag and show you the exceptions; so this information is just one keypress away.